# How to do a long press on element in appium-android?

Tags: appium-android

appium=1.9.0
android devices
windows 10

Long press on a element is not working

I have already tried with :

1. ```
   <MobileElement longpress = (MobileElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).
       until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("msgContent")));
   new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(longpress).perform();
   ```

   error:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Parameters were
>   incorrect. We wanted {"required":["actions"]} and you sent ["element"]

2. ```
   TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
   action.longPress((LongPressOptions) element).release().perform();
   ```

   error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16 cannot be cast to
>   io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions

3. ```
   new TouchAction(driver).press(ElementOption.element(element)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(20))).release().perform();
   ```

error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16 to
>   org.openqa.selenium.internal.HasIdentity

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the element in "press" pass the coordinates of the element, check below code

1. First locate your element
2. Pass the x and y coordinates of the element in press

   ```
   WebElement ele = driver.findElement(BY.xpath("your_element_xpath"));
   Point location = ele.getLocation();
   new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(location.getX(), location.getY())).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(20))).release().perform();
   ```

this code should hold the element for 20 seconds